# Unit Testing WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing

I'm new to programming and c#, and have been assigned the task of writing unit tests for legacy code in preparation for big DB change.

The more I read on unit testing, the more skeptical I am on my approach.

How would you approach writting a unit test for the following?
Currently I've just been unit testing my Data Access Layer Methods, ensuring they return back a result? But apparently unit test are supposed to be independent of any outside environments?

How can I test my application, when almost everything is making a call to the database or stored procedure?

My Form Code:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadAllCountries()
}

private static void LoadAllCountries()
{
    List<nsHacAppMod.ViewCountryInfo> oReturn = moBusinessServices.GetAllCountries();
}
```

My Data Access Layer

```
public List<nsAppMod.ViewCountryInfo> GetAllCountries()
{
    List<nsAppMod.ViewCountryInfo> oReturn;

    var oResult = from c in moDataContext.ViewCountryInfos
                  select c;

    oReturn = oResult.ToList();

    return oReturn;
}
```

My current unit test for this code, is this acceptable? If not what would you test?

```
[Test]
public void LoadAllCountries()
{
    hac.CatalogSamples cs = new hac.CatalogSamples();
    var countries = cs.GetAllCountries().count();

    Assert.GreaterOrEqual(countries 0);
}
```

Comment: what do you get when you run your test.. this is more of an Opinionated question because not everyone write `Unit Test Code` the same way.. heck I wonder how many developers out there even write it on a daily basis anyway I don't see anything wrong with that however I am hesitant to put `Assertion` coding in my prod environment personally have you googled and best practices in regards to Unit Testing..? I would write 3 types of test when doing unit testing `Negative, Positive and Exception`

Comment: The important thing with unit tests is you are trying to "Prove" something. What does your current test "prove"? (`cs.GetAllCountries` will return 0 or more records) Is that information useful at all?

Comment: You need integration tests (tests that use outside resources aka the database) for your data access methods and then your unit tests just ensure that the integration tested methods were called in the correct place

Comment: @DJKRAZE you don't put the unit tests in prod code, you put them in class libraries that are only built in debug mode

Comment: @DJKRAZE Not in prod, on test environment

Comment: I know that.. but I am speaking from experience because I have ran into 2 projects where a developer did such thing I know not to do that..

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  I just want to check that the stored procedure has been called, successfully returning 0 or more results. Integration testing I assume will be verify the right results are being returned

Comment: Which are you trying to test, that `LoadAllCountries()` calls `GetAllCountries()` or that `GetAllCountries()` calls `ViewCountryInfos`?

Comment: I would be testing the GetAllCountries calls ViewCountryInfos. I don't see a reason to test that LoadAllCountries calls GetAllCountries , since it is clearly visible in the code, and there is no calculations or results.

Comment: The reason to write unit tests is so that you can refactor and not worry about breaking working code. It might be perfectly visible right now, but if someone deletes it later you want a test to fail to alert you

Comment: How can you be new to programming and C# and be given the task to write Unit tests? This should be your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unit test data access things if your context is based off of an interface like IContext it can be faked, and you can then test just the code you are trying to test like the GetAllCountries() method.

However, other than the try catch, there is no actual logic to test. I look at it like this: If it is a property that has no logic in it, or methods too, it's not worth testing.
Using a mocking framework like [FakeItEasy](http://fakeiteasy.github.io/) I would test this method just like this:

```
    public class ClassToTest
{
    internal virtual MoDataContext CreateContext()
    {
        return new MoDataContext();
    }

    public List<ViewCountryInfo> GetAllCountries()
    {
        List<ViewCountryInfo> oReturn = null;

        try
        {
            var oResult = from c in this.CreateContext().ViewCountryInfos
                          select c;

            oReturn = oResult.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return oReturn;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test_GetAllCountries_ResultCountShouldBeGreaterThan0()
    {
        var fakeData = new List<ViewCountryInfo>();
        fakeData.Add(new ViewCountryInfo());

        var sut = A.Fake<ClassToTest>();
        A.CallTo(sut).CallsBaseMethod();
        A.CallTo(() => sut.CreateContext()).Returns(fakeData);

        var result = sut.GetAllCountries();

        Assert.IsTrue(result.Count() > 0);
    }
```

Comment: One of the other things I would like to mention is that it is really hard to fake things or test static methods.